# Use Intl.Collator in a Firefox Add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to access [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) in a Firefox add-on built using the SDK?

It’s available on the global window object of ordinary page scripts, but it’s not defined in the global scope of an addon or, apparently, in the window of a [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). Any other ways to access it? A [page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker)? An [XPCOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference)?

Comment: This is supported from firefox 29 so I can't tell you but try this. Go to privelaged scope in scrachpad and run this `alert(Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.Intl.Collator)` if you don't get undefined you can use that. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t realize Firefox support for `Intl.Collator` will only arrive in Firefox 29. I had seen that [bugzil.la/769872](http://bugzil.la/769872) was fixed a year ago and assumed it was available in the release channel by now. Looks like I should have read [bugzil.la/853301](http://bugzil.la/853301) too. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intl.Collator` is available in an addon’s global scope in Firefox 29+.

`Intl.Collator` support only arrived in Firefox 29, currently available in [the Aurora channel](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/) (see [bugzil.la/853301](http://bugzil.la/853301)).

Answer (score 0):

```
var { Cc, Ci } = require("chrome");
Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService)
```

or

```
var { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
getMostRecentBrowserWindow() // window scope of most recent active browser window
```

Comment: What if there is no browser window open erik? Is it possible to pull this from hidden window?

Comment: `nsIIOService` doesn’t help. It was just an example of an XPCOM interface that I threw into my question for illustration purposes, hoping that there might a different one that provides the functionality of `Intl.Collator`.

Comment: Looks like `'Intl' in getMostRecentBrowserWindow()` is `false`.

Comment: do `getMostRecentBrowserWindow().contentWindow.Intl`

Comment: Wait... `getMostRecentBrowserWindow().Intl.Collator` is available in Firefox 29. Turns out `Intl.Collator` is also available in an addon’s default global scope in Firefox 29, so my question is kind of pointless. (I had been using the current release, Firefox 27.) Thanks for the help, and sorry for the trouble.